# Why the scaling of the object is changing all the time nonstop up and down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What i want to do is when i press F once on the first script and it's true to display the object then start the coroutine to change the object scale on the second object.

The problem is that it's scaling the object non stop up and down and i want it to scale it once up and if i will press F again to not displaying the object scale it back down once.

The first script where i press on F:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DroidMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject droid;
    public ChangeScale changeScale;

    private float distance;
    private Camera cam; 

    private void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        distance = Vector3.Distance(cam.transform.position, droid.transform.position);
        droid.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            droid.SetActive(!droid.activeInHierarchy);
            if (droid.activeInHierarchy == true)
            {
                changeScale.Scale();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second script that scale the object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;

    private float _currentScale = InitScale;
    private const float TargetScale = 1.1f;
    private const float InitScale = 0f;
    private const int FramesCount = 100;
    private const float AnimationTimeSeconds = 2;
    private float _deltaTime = AnimationTimeSeconds / FramesCount;
    private float _dx = (TargetScale - InitScale) / FramesCount;
    private bool _upScale = true;

    private IEnumerator Breath()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while (_upScale)
            {
                _currentScale += _dx;
                if (_currentScale > TargetScale)
                {
                    _upScale = false;
                    _currentScale = TargetScale;
                }
                objectToScale.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * _currentScale;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(_deltaTime);
            }

            while (!_upScale)
            {
                _currentScale -= _dx;
                if (_currentScale < InitScale)
                {
                    _upScale = true;
                    _currentScale = InitScale;
                }
                objectToScale.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * _currentScale;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(_deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Scale()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Breath());
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (true)` = "repeat forever"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't test it out myself, I made some minor changes that I believe should give you the desired behaviour. The first script becomes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DroidMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject droid;
    public ChangeScale changeScale;

    private float distance;
    private Camera cam; 

    private void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        distance = Vector3.Distance(cam.transform.position, droid.transform.position);
        droid.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            changeScale.Scale();
        }
    }
}
```

The second script becomes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;

    private float _currentScale = InitScale;
    private const float TargetScale = 1.1f;
    private const float InitScale = 0f;
    private const int FramesCount = 100;
    private const float AnimationTimeSeconds = 2;
    private float _deltaTime = AnimationTimeSeconds / FramesCount;
    private float _dx = (TargetScale - InitScale) / FramesCount;
    private bool _upScaling = false;
    private bool _downScaling = false;

    private IEnumerator ScaleUp()
    {
        _upScaling = true;
        while (_upScaling)
        {
            _currentScale += _dx;
            if (_currentScale > TargetScale)
            {
                _upScaling = false;
                _currentScale = TargetScale;
            }
            objectToScale.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * _currentScale;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleDown()
    {
        _downScaling = true;
        while (_downScaling)
        {
            _currentScale -= _dx;
            if (_currentScale < InitScale)
            {
                _downScaling = false;
                _currentScale = InitScale;
                droid.SetActive(false);
            }
            objectToScale.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * _currentScale;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_deltaTime);
        }
    }

    public void Scale(bool scaleUp)
    {
        if (!droid.activeInHierarchy) {
            droid.SetActive(true);
            StartCoroutine(ScaleUp());
        }

        if (_downScaling)
            StartCoroutine(ScaleUp());
        else
            StartCoroutine(ScaleDown());
    }
}
```

I basically made 2 different routines; one that scales up and one that scales down. When you press F, I adapt the active state of the object, and depending on that state the right coroutine is called.

Comment: Don't just post a code. Please explain your answer. Tell OP what you changed or what you think the problem is.

Comment: I was in progress of typing a small explanation, apologies.

Comment: @GlennCodes Thank you. The ScaleUp part is working fine the ScaleDown part make it just gone the object and not scaling down slowly like the ScaleUp.. The ScaleDown just make the object gone at once.

Comment: Ah is the droid GameObject also the GameObject we are scaling? I assumed it was a different object since there were two different scripts. I'll make some changes.

Comment: @GlennCodes in both scripts it's the same object to scale. At the first script i called it droid in the second objecttoscale but they are both the same in the editor in the inspector i drag the same object(droid) to both scripts. It's just the ChangeScale more global script so i called the object variable objectToScale.

Comment: @jdoedoedoedoe Made some changes. As I can't test it myself right now, I don't know for sure whether it works. I basically just decide whether the scaleup or scaledown routine has to be called based on both the active state of the object and whether it's already downscaling or not.

Comment: @GlennCodes I found the problem. First i changed back the code in both scripts to your first solution. When scaling back down i'm also making the droid not to be active.  This making the droid scaling down back at once. Instead doing: droid.SetActive(!droid.activeInHierarchy); when pressing F i removed this line and added local private bool and did when i press F: toDisplay = !toDisplay; and changeScale.Scale(toDisplay); and now it's working.